# MH4U English Demo Online Multiplayer connection error

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, monster-hunter-4-ultimate

Yesterday I downloaded the MH4U demo from the Nintendo store, played solo for a bit, and then tried to set up a hunt with a friend online.

I created a Hall to hunt Tetsucabra, added a passcode, and sent my friend the Hall ID.

When he tried to join, it asked him for the passcode, accepted it, and after that he said it threw an error.
So we reversed the process; he created a Hall and I tried to connect. Same deal.
Error [006-0612](http://www.nintendo.com/consumer/wfc/en_na/ds/results.jsp?error_code=006-0612&system=3DS), please try again later.

As per the Nintendo support link, we tried changing our 3DS' DNS settings to Google DNS on the off chance that helped. We tried the same thing (I created a hall and he tried to connect, then vice-versa) and got the same result.

Then I found a [Chinese post](http://corrupt1022.pixnet.net/blog/post/31970697-[%E9%81%8A%E6%88%B2%E5%BF%83%E5%BE%97]-n3ds%E9%80%A3%E7%B7%9A-%E9%8C%AF%E8%AA%A4%E4%BB%A3%E7%A2%BC006-0612-%E8%A7%A3%E6%B1%BA%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95() that I do not fully understand, but seems to suggest setting your 3DS to your router's DMZ. I cannot do this, as the 3DS requires that it have a static IP when set to the DMZ, while my router requires than any device set to the DMZ have a dynamic IP.

Anyone else know where to go from here? Aside from buying a better router.

Comment: I have never seen a router that "required a dynamic IP to use DMZ". Most router allow you to specify the internal IP address to set to DMZ. Either set this to the same (current) IP that your 3DS uses, or a static IP that your 3DS pulls. If you're having a problem with other devices "using" the IP that your 3DS is trying to set as static, try setting it to the last IP in your router's IP range. Also, are you able to connect to anyone else? Is your friend able to connect to anyone else? Have you ensured there are no updates that need to be installed?

Comment: `I have never seen a router that "required a dynamic IP to use DMZ". Most router allow you to specify the internal IP address to set to DMZ.` I know, I was pretty damn surprised too.
`Either set this to the same (current) IP that your 3DS uses, or a static IP that your 3DS pulls.` The router configuration page quite literally will not let me do that when my 3DS pulls a static IP, which is consistent with my ISP's claim that this model won't do that. And the 3DS refuses to access the internet _at all_ if it's DMZed and its IP is dynamic, which is consistent with Nintendo's documentation.

Comment: `If you're having a problem with other devices "using" the IP that your 3DS is trying to set as static, try setting it to the last IP in your router's IP range.` Not an issue.
`Also, are you able to connect to anyone else? Is your friend able to connect to anyone else? Have you ensured there are no updates that need to be installed?` We intend to try that as soon as we have the chance.

Comment: @Thebluefish I might try to configure the router via Telnet later instead and see if I get any further that way, but I'm not hopeful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### To the poor souls with a `Technicolour TG582n` modem/router (or similar)

1. [Your modem/router requires a device to have a dynamically (DHCP) assigned address in order to use the DMZ](http://help.spark.co.nz/app/answers/detail/a_id/20201/~/dmz-mode---thomson%2Ftechnicolor-modems)
2. [Your 3DS appears to need a static address to access the internet when using the DMZ](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/660/~/how-to-configure-a-routers-dmz)
3. 1 and 2 contradict each other.

*The most obvious solution is to get a new modem/router.*

*If you have a spare router with no modem functionality, you could also try setting your modem/router up in bridge mode to your spare router and then using the DMZ functionality on that one instead.*

Note that to set up bridge mode with a TG582n, you will need to use Telnet and the [command line interface](http://wiki.aa.org.uk/images/3/33/TG582n_CLI_Guide_v1.0_public.pdf). Not recommended if you don't know what those are, attempt at your own risk, YMMV, &c, &c. Less terrible modem/routers often let you easily configure bridge mode through the web interface, but then again, less terrible modem/routers probably either just work with MH4U or at least don't require a dynamic addressed device for the DMZ.

### To anyone else

1. The issue could be on the other end (e.g. if you get the error joining a game, it could be caused by a problem on your end or a problem on the host's end).
2. Check your modem/router's firewall.
3. Look up your modem/router's DMZ settings and how to use them. This will be somewhat specific to each model. If it works with devices that have statically assigned IPs, try assigning your 3DS a static IP and then setting that IP to the DMZ. [Nintendo provides a guide for setting a static IP on your 3DS.](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/671).

---

I'll try to add a list of modem/routers my friends and I have successfully played with. Bear in mind that other factors, like firewalls or weird ISP settings