# Online dome Multiplayer connection error

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, monster-hunter-4-ultimate

As i have to less Points to answer and/or comment this post here ( Error 006-0612, please try again later.)
[MH4U English Demo Online Multiplayer connection error](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/201932/mh4u-english-demo-online-multiplayer-connection-error)
I have to write my own question and suggestion.

The most important thing is, what the hell did the developers think???

The Connection of the game is mainly done via UDP, so far so good, but if my 3DS is behind a Firewall (as 99.999% of the 3DSes will be) why not use a technique like Skype one did? UDP hole punching?

My Fix for the Monster hunter Connection Problem was the following.
I observed the Traffic as flowed, and saw a lot of successful connections to the outside world. (on the internal interface em1)

```
1423595007.171129 IP 90.13.170.119.63959 > 192.168.1.13.64764: UDP, length 75
1423595007.173154 IP 192.168.1.13.64764 > 90.13.170.119.63959: UDP, length 75
1423595007.204274 IP 192.168.1.13.64764 > 108.72.36.79.55263: UDP, length 75
1423595007.206327 IP 192.168.1.13.64764 > 90.13.170.119.63959: UDP, length 67
1423595007.206412 IP 108.72.36.79.55263 > 192.168.1.13.64764: UDP, length 117
1423595007.237530 IP 192.168.1.13.64764 > 108.72.36.79.55263: UDP, length 75
1423595007.342280 IP 90.13.170.119.63959 > 192.168.1.13.64764: UDP, length 67
1423595007.506239 IP 108.72.36.79.55263 > 192.168.1.13.64764: UDP, length 67
1423595007.535475 IP 192.168.1.13.64764 > 108.72.36.79.55263: UDP, length 75
1423595007.701361 IP 192.168.1.13.64764 > 109.29.61.79.58787: UDP, length 117
1423595007.813428 IP 108.72.36.79.55263 > 192.168.1.13.64764: UDP, length 157
1423595007.838472 IP 109.29.61.79.58787 > 192.168.1.13.64764: UDP, length 75
1423595007.864715 IP 109.29.61.79.58787 > 192.168.1.13.64764: UDP, length 75
1423595007.868165 IP 192.168.1.13.64764 > 108.72.36.79.55263: UDP, length 67
1423595007.897841 IP 109.29.61.79.58787 > 192.168.1.13.64764: UDP, length 75
```

But when the error strikes i always noticed the following connections hitting my Firewall (freebsd, pflog device)

```
00:00:00.023437 rule 0..16777216/0(match): block in on em0: 112.198.77.27.34612 > 192.168.1.13.50169: UDP, length 25
00:00:00.537435 rule 0..16777216/0(match): block in on em0: 112.198.77.27.34612 > 192.168.1.13.50169: UDP, length 25
00:00:00.514356 rule 0..16777216/0(match): block in on em0: 112.198.77.27.34612 > 192.168.1.13.50169: UDP, length 25
00:00:00.538893 rule 0..16777216/0(match): block in on em0: 112.198.77.27.34612 > 192.168.1.13.50169: UDP, length 25
```

(192.168.1.13 is the 3DS)

On multiple connections we saw that the port always changed, so a single port forwarding was not possible.

The Solution in The end was fix the 3DS IP address in my network, and forward one of my public IPs to the 3DS (unfortunately I have a /29 subnet)

So as silly as i first thought that putting a 3DS into a DMZ might is, it seems to be the solution.

(pf.conf)

```
     binat on $ext_if inet from 192.168.1.13 to any -> $public_ip
...
     pass log quick from any to 192.168.1.13 keep state
```

Could someone please explain what the real fix could/should be???

EDIT:
btw. I don't provide upnp on my fw, as i don't like unknown listening traffic, and is was NEVER necessary for ANY game in the last 5(?) years....

Comment: This is getting a liiittle outside of our expertise.  Diagnosing firewall connection issues isn't really a gamer skill.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a network issue, which out of scope as to what we can answer on Gaming.SE.

Comment: I created this post because i was unable to answer, and comment on exactly this post. I just wanted to give a hint, or help anybody else what he could do, and why this happens.

Comment: @Daywalker You were unable to comment or answer that post because you're not allowed to answer protected questions until you gain some reputation. Why you need to gain some reputation first is to demonstrate that you understand how the site works. Using this question to write an answer to another question demonstrates a lack of understanding of how the site works, which ironically shows that the block is justified.

Comment: So if you want to answer that question... look around, observe how the site works, read our [tour] and consult the [help] for anything you're unclear on, and answer some questions usefully. It will only take *one* upvote on an answer you write to get enough reputation for that. Then you can answer protected questions, like the one about the MH4U demo.

Comment: Thank you for the lesson on stackexchange ;) But I was looking for a quick, lets say, info post about what is going on in the background. If I so happened to annoy anybody with it, then i apologize and you will never hear again from me, because i usually don't post on this site (gaming). So, yes I was to lazy to get one reputation, but as far as I read, i needet 10 to answer OR comment. But maybe i was mistaken. But as everything already happened, feel free to delete or ignore the post.

Comment: @Daywalker Hi, OP of the linked question here. I think the devs just assumed that everyone would have a good quality uPnP implementation =/
When you say _the port always changed_, you mean it is randomised? (I would test it myself, but I'm at work.) Does it seem to be in a specific range that you can identify?

Comment: @IskarJarak Hi, Well I am of course not sure what the devs assumed :) but I just tried and installed miniupnpd on my FreeBSD box. As i am not the owner of the 3DS I'll have to wait till I see him again today, and check if it is working with UPNP enabled. The Strange thing for me is that other SHO routers most likely also habe UPNP activated and are unable to establish a successful connection. But I will post my results today.